# Is it necessary to install Visual Studio for Angular2? Why?

Tags: angular

Is it necessary to install Visual Studio for Angular2? Why?
I am little confuse about it.

I looked at one of the websites and they tell to install it in them step.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is not required to start to play with Angular. You can use any text editor you like. On the site you linked to, they are using Visual Studio Code because it is a well-known IDE. Note, that [Visial Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is not the same as [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en/vs/).

They also install GIT and it is not necessary too.

[Here you can find IDEs recommend by Angular Team.](https://angular.io/resources)

Answer (score 2):

This link does not work so this is a stab in the dark. Angular relies on typescript. You do not need visual studio to use TypeScript you just need to create a TypeScript compilation pipeline to convert the .ts files into javascript.

Plenty of code orientated text editors have plugins to help deal with .ts files

Answer (score 2):

No it is not necessary it is just an IDE you can use whichever IDE you like even 
notepad (windows users), Here is a comparison of IDE you can pick https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments